# Varnish failed after configure

Tags: apache, ubuntu, magento2, varnish, varnish-vcl

Regards to all,
I installed the varnish on my Ubuntu 20.04 server. On which Magento2 and Apache web services work. When I apply the varnish according to instructions, it will not work. Can anyone help.
Thanks in advance everyone!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfQg6.png

Comment: The error clearly refers to permission error. Can you please share your systemd unit file, and the contents of the `override.conf` file?

Comment: This is the configuration, in my answer I posted three pictures.@ThijsFeryn Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that your `varnish.service` file is owned by `vcache` and has `rw-r--r--` permissions.

I advise you to perform `chown root:root varnish.service`, because I'm assuming *systemd* doesn't have the right permissions to open the file.

Please also verify that the service files are hosted inside `/etc/systemd/sytem`, because one of your screenshots indicates that some of these files are stored in `/etc/systemd`.

> Long story short, *systemd* will try to start services using the `root` user. Make sure this user has read and execute permissions to access this file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0f2A.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xn8j.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HAF6.png